# Add background color to an HTML table cell without using background-color?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add (background) color to a table cell other than the background-color style attribute? I have tables with programmatically generated textual content and background colors, which may update on their own. I'd like to temporarily highlight certain cells (think of a moving cursor), ideally without touching the existing code or interfere with the background-color styling.

Possibly I could calculate some overlay DIVs, but I'd prefer anything I could try on the cells themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `background-image` and gradient:

```css
td {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}


/* your code */
td:hover {
  background-image:linear-gradient(red,red);
}
/**/
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td style="background-color:#ddd!important">cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#f3f3f3">cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A pseudo element can also do the job:

```css
td {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}


/* your code */
td {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
} 
td:hover::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:red;
}
/**/
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td>
    <td style="background-color:#ddd!important">cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#f3f3f3">cell</td>
    <td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! The gradient solution is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: @user3107036 don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue

Answer (score 2):

You could use an inset `box-shadow` to cover your `background`

```css
td {
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
}

td:hover, .highlight {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px yellow;
}
td.highlight:hover  {/* ? needed ? */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      cell to hover
    </td>
    <td>
      cell to hover
    </td>
    <td class="highlight">
      cell to highlight
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```